# I am trying to combine datatables with the row grouping plugin, pivot.js, and sparklines

Tags: jquery, pivot-table, datatables, sparklines

The need:

- Row level grouping that goes n-levels deep (eg greater than 3)
- Complex headers with hide and show functionality
- Summary rows for pivot (Row headers with sums, avg, ... across columns)
  - General use is business metric name as the row with time intervals as columns
  - This needs to be displayed for all levels of row grouping as well
- Cross column business math at the pivot row detail and row grouping levels
- Sparklines on the pivot row detail and row grouping levels

I have read and tried, with one of the other developers on my team, to bake all of this functionality into a single grid with DataTables as the base to work from. But at every turn I keep running into what seems to be limitations.

I need options that are preferably open source, but would will take a vender if anyone knows of one that can actually handle all of the above. And yes I know excel can do all of this but we are trying to move to web based analysis versus offline.